# JSCH exception: Could not send file per SFTP: org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session

Tags: exception, spring-batch, jsch

I am using Spring Batch to perform SFTP to server. The following is the error stack trace I am getting:

```
org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session
    at com.example.util.SFTPTasklet.execute(SFTPTasklet.java:98)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:131)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:198)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:165)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
    at com.example.main.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:213)
      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:295)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:190)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:182)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.handler.FileTransferringMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(FileTransferringMessageHandler.java:112)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:178)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:149)
    at com.example.util.SFTPTasklet.execute(SFTPTasklet.java:95)
    ... 33 more
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to connect
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:250)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:316)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.io.IOException: inputstream is closed
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.start(ChannelSftp.java:242)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Channel.java:200)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Channel.java:144)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:245)
    ... 45 more
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: inputstream is closed
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.fill(ChannelSftp.java:2335)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.header(ChannelSftp.java:2359)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.start(ChannelSftp.java:211)
    ... 48 more
```

Java code:

```
  @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
    File path = new File(reprintOutputPath);
    File[] files = path.listFiles();
    if (files != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (files[i].isFile()) { // this line weeds out other directories/folders
                File file = new File(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
                if (file.exists()) {
                    Message<File> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(file).build();
                    try {
                        sftpChannel.send(message);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        loggerObj.error("Could not send file per SFTP: " + e);
                        loggerObj.error(e.fillInStackTrace());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    loggerObj.error("File does not exist.");
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        loggerObj.error("no files found in the folder");
    }
    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
}
```

Any suggestions why I am getting the exceptions? The user id and password are correct.

Comment: The same code is working fine in the lower environments. Only in my Production environment I am getting this error

Comment: maybe config differences between environments?

Comment: Show us the JSch log: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Logger.java.html

Answer (score 0):

The port for SFTP may have been blocked by your firewall.